# Search in finder folder doesn't work - Mac OS Ventura

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, search

I'm trying to search in finder in specific folders. The search works on ''my Mac'' or in spotlight but not in the folder in question. I've tried the spotlight-privacy trick, tried reinstalling the OS, nothing is working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I'm searching a file in the finder search bar, nothing appears (and the file is definitely in that folder). However if I change the search to ''this Mac'' I can see the file - same if I search in spotlight.

Comment: Doesn't have something to do with the search settings? The second screenshot says that you're search a "Quote" but not in the first screenshot?